# Bookmark Program using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input, hyperlink

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="heading">Book Search</h1>
        <input placeholder="Type Book name" class="searchBar" id="searchInput" type="search">
        <br>
        <select id="selectDisplayCount" class="options">
            <option selected value="10">10 Books</option>
            <option value="20">20 Books</option>
            <option value="30">30 Books</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="searchResults">
        <div class="col-12 d-none mt-5" id="spinner">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
                <div class="spinner-border" role="status"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
let searchInputEl = document.getElementById("searchInput");
let spinnerEl = document.getElementById("spinner");
let searchresultsEl = document.getElementById("searchResults")
let selectDisplayCountEl = document.getElementById("selectDisplayCount");
let bookcount = selectDisplayCountEl.value;

let formData = {
    count: "10 Books",
}

function createAndAppendSearchResult(result) {
    let {
        title,
        imageLink,
        author
    } = result;
    let resultItemEl = document.createElement("div");
    resultItemEl.classList.add("country-card", "col-6", "mr-auto", "ml-auto", "d-flex", "flex-column")
    searchresultsEl.appendChild(resultItemEl);

    let imageEl = document.createElement("img");
    imageEl.classList.add("image", "mt-auto", "mb-auto")
    imageEl.src = imageLink;
    resultItemEl.appendChild(imageEl);

    let authorEl = document.createElement("p");
    authorEl.classList.add("author-name")
    authorEl.textContent = author;
    resultItemEl.appendChild(authorEl);
}

function displaySearchResults(searchresult) {
    for (let result of searchresult) {
        let titleName = result.title
        if (titleName.includes(searchInputEl.value)) {
            createAndAppendSearchResult(result);
        } else {
            searchInputEl.textontent = "No reuslts found";
        }
    }
}

function searchBook(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        let url = "https://apis.ccbp.in/book-store?title=kalam&maxResults=30" + searchInput;
        let options = {
            method: "GET"
        }
        spinnerEl.classList.remove("d-none");
        searchresultsEl.classList.add("d-none");
        fetch(url, options)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(jsonData) {
                searchresultsEl.classList.remove("d-none");
                spinnerEl.classList.add("d-none");
                console.log(jsonData)
                let {
                    search_results
                } = jsonData;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData))
                displaySearchResults(search_results);
            })
    }
}


selectDisplayCountEl.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    formData.count = event.target.value;
    console.log(formData.count)
});
searchInputEl.addEventListener("keydown", searchBook);
```

errors I am getting

When a value is entered in the HTML input element with id searchInput, x books option is selected in the HTML select element with id selectDisplayCount, an HTTP GET request with a valid url parameters title and maxResults should be made

When a value is entered in the HTML input element with id searchInput, x books option is selected in the HTML select element with id selectDisplayCount, an HTTP GET request should be made to fetch and display x book items

how exactly it should work is:

https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/content/dynamic-webapps/book_search_output.gif

```js
let searchInputEl = document.getElementById("searchInput");
let spinnerEl = document.getElementById("spinner");
let searchresultsEl = document.getElementById("searchResults")
let selectDisplayCountEl = document.getElementById("selectDisplayCount");
let bookcount = selectDisplayCountEl.value;

let formData = {
    count: "10 Books",
}

function createAndAppendSearchResult(result) {
    let {
        title,
        imageLink,
        author
    } = result;
    let resultItemEl = document.createElement("div");
    resultItemEl.classList.add("country-card", "col-6", "mr-auto", "ml-auto", "d-flex", "flex-column")
    searchresultsEl.appendChild(resultItemEl);

    let imageEl = document.createElement("img");
    imageEl.classList.add("image", "mt-auto", "mb-auto")
    imageEl.src = imageLink;
    resultItemEl.appendChild(imageEl);

    let authorEl = document.createElement("p");
    authorEl.classList.add("author-name")
    authorEl.textContent = author;
    resultItemEl.appendChild(authorEl);
}

function displaySearchResults(searchresult) {
    for (let result of searchresult) {
        let titleName = result.title
        if (titleName.includes(searchInputEl.value)) {
            createAndAppendSearchResult(result);
        } else {
            searchInputEl.textontent = "No reuslts found";
        }
    }
}

function searchBook(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        let url = "https://apis.ccbp.in/book-store?title=kalam&maxResults=30" + searchInput;
        let options = {
            method: "GET"
        }
        spinnerEl.classList.remove("d-none");
        searchresultsEl.classList.add("d-none");
        fetch(url, options)
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(jsonData) {
                searchresultsEl.classList.remove("d-none");
                spinnerEl.classList.add("d-none");
                console.log(jsonData)
                let {
                    search_results
                } = jsonData;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonData))
                displaySearchResults(search_results);
            })
    }
}


selectDisplayCountEl.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    formData.count = event.target.value;
    console.log(formData.count)
});
searchInputEl.addEventListener("keydown", searchBook);
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z' crossorigin='anonymous' />
<script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js' integrity='sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
<script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js' integrity='sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
<script src='//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js' integrity='sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>

<div class='container'>
    <h1 class='heading'>Book Search</h1>
    <input placeholder='Type Book name' class='searchBar' id='searchInput' type='search'>
    <br>
    <select id='selectDisplayCount' class='options'>
        <option selected value='10'>10 Books</option>
        <option value='20'>20 Books</option>
        <option value='30'>30 Books</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id='searchResults'>
    <div class='col-12 d-none mt-5' id='spinner'>
        <div class='d-flex flex-row justify-content-center'>
            <div class='spinner-border' role='status'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `searchInput` method defined? Or is that supposed to be `searchBook`?

Comment: yeah It's actually searchBook I might have typed out wrong

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is that you are having as it is not immediately obvious from the question.

Comment: AFTER completion of the code it should work like this : (https://assets.ccbp.in/frd/content/dynamic-webapps/book_search_output.gif ). But in my program when I clicked submit it is not directing to the URLs and its not giving the result I hoped for.

Answer (score 0):

According to the animated GIF the `select` menu ought to also trigger the AJAX request to the 3rd party api however according to your code it simply updates the global variable`formData`. As both the `select` and the `keydown/enter` are to trigger the same actions a single event handler can be used. With a little re-writing of the above and some new functions one can simplify the code to accomplish what you are trying (I think) to do.

The following code snippet omits the various external scripts and stylesheets used in  the original but will serve to illustrate the result.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{      
  let oRes=document.getElementById('searchResults');
  let oText=document.getElementById('searchInput');
  let oSel=document.getElementById('selectDisplayCount');
  let oSpin=document.getElementById('spinner');

  const baseurl='https://apis.ccbp.in/book-store';

  // utility to ease construction of full urls in modern browsers
  const buildurl=function( endpoint, params ){
    let url=new URL( endpoint );
      url.search = new URLSearchParams( params ).toString();
    return url;
  };
  
  // utility method to create new DOM elements
  // where t=node type, a=attributes & p=parent to append to.
  const create=function(t,a,p){
    let el = ( typeof( t )=='undefined' || t==null ) ? document.createElement( 'div' ) : document.createElement( t );
    let _arr=['innerHTML','innerText','html','text'];
    for( let x in a ) if( a.hasOwnProperty( x ) && !~_arr.indexOf( x ) ) el.setAttribute( x, a[ x ] );
    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerHTML') || a.hasOwnProperty('html') ) el.innerHTML=a.innerHTML || a.html;
    if( a.hasOwnProperty('innerText') || a.hasOwnProperty('text') ) el.innerText=a.innerText || a.text;
    if( p!=null ) typeof( p )=='object' ? p.appendChild( el ) : document.getElementById( p ).appendChild( el );
    return el;
  };


  // The callback method to generate output HTML
  const callback=(json)=>{
    toggleclasses(false);

    let data=json.search_results;
    oRes.innerHTML='';

    Object.keys( data ).forEach( k => {
      let obj=data[ k ];

      let div=create(null,{'class':'country-card col-6 mr-auto ml-auto d-flex flex-column'},oRes);
      create('h1',{text:obj.title},div);
      create('img',{src:obj.imageLink,'class':'image mt-auto mb-auto'},div);
      create('p',{text:obj.author,'class':'author-name'},div);
    });             
  };


  // helper to switch classes as per original
  const toggleclasses=(b)=>{
    switch(b){
      case true:
        oSpin.classList.remove('d-none');
        oRes.classList.add('d-none');                       
      break;
      case false:
        oSpin.classList.add('d-none');
        oRes.classList.remove('d-none');
      break;
    }
  };


  // single event handler to send AJAX request
  const requesthandler=(e)=>{
    if( e.key === 'Enter' || e.type=='change' ) {
      toggleclasses(true);

      if( oText.value=='')return;

      let args={
        title:oText.value,
        maxResults:oSel.value
      };
      fetch( buildurl( baseurl, args ) )
        .then( r=>r.json() )
        .then( json=>callback( json ) )
    }
  };




  oSel.addEventListener('change',requesthandler);
  oText.addEventListener('keydown',requesthandler);
});
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <h1 class='heading'>Book Search</h1>
  <input placeholder='Type Book name' class='searchBar' id='searchInput' type='search' />

  <br />

  <select id='selectDisplayCount' class='options'>
  <option value='1'>1 Book
  <option value='5'>5 Books
    <option selected value='10'>10 Books
    <option value='20'>20 Books
    <option value='30'>30 Books
  <option value='50'>50 Books
  <option value='100'>100 Books
  </select>
</div>

<div id='searchResults'>
  <div class='col-12 d-none mt-5' id='spinner'>
    <div class='d-flex flex-row justify-content-center'>
      <div class='spinner-border' role='status'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You. I appreciate it.

Comment: But I don't know half of it. Is it alright to make it a bit simple? So that you add to the already existing code and not a completely different one so that I have a better understanding. I am still on the learning side. I hope it's not too much to ask.